# Is Psychiatric History an Obstacle to Obtaining a Part 107 Certificate?

Tags: regulations

Certain psychiatric conditions will prevent persons from obtaining a commercial pilot's license. Do the same restrictions apply to Part 107? If so, what means are there of obtaining clearance?

Background Reference: [Guide for Aviation Medical Examiners: Item 47. Psychiatric Conditions](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/app_process/exam_tech/item47/amd/table/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no specific medical restrictions placed on drone pilots in the US, however the pilot should not have reason to believe their state of health (physical and/or mental) will affect the flight:

> § 107.17 Medical condition.
>
> No person may manipulate the flight controls of a small unmanned
> aircraft system or act as a remote pilot in command, visual observer,
> or direct participant in the operation of the small unmanned aircraft
> if he or she knows or has reason to know that he or she has a physical
> or mental condition that would interfere with the safe operation of
> the small unmanned aircraft system.

*[Source: eCFR 14.I.F.107.B.17](https://ecfr.federalregister.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-107/subpart-B/section-107.17)*

Comment: Also, the TSA Background Check includes this restriction in [Disqualifying Offenses and Other Factors](https://www.tsa.gov/disqualifying-offenses-factors): "An applicant will also be disqualified if he or she has either been adjudicated as lacking mental capacity or is involuntarily committed to a mental health facility."